# How to use and show embedded subtitles in mp4/mkv video in HTML video tag

Tags: audio-streaming, video-subtitles

I'm trying to make a video player in browser using React Native Expo. The purpose is to play a streaming mp4/mkv via url with content type video/mp4 or video/mkv.

The videos from the provider will have embedded different audios and subtitles.

I was wondering how to a extract the subtitles and audio and make selectable list so that the user can select the desired subtitle or audio on fly along with the playing video?

I have successfully tried to use FFmpeg and FFprobe to view the streams of audios and subtitles. I Then tried to use mux.js to manipulate the stream video stream data but unfortunately i couldn't achieve it.

Appreciate all suggestions.